# How increasing current in conductor increase magnetic force of horshoe magnet

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Can someone explain how increasing the amount of current through a conductor increase the force it experiences when a horseshoe magnet is placed around,how can increasing the current in electromagnet increase magnetic force of horseshoe magnet?

Comment: There is no "magnetic force of a magnet" as an intrinsic property. There is a "magnetic field of a magnet". The conductor interacts with the magnetic field of the magnet.

Answer (score 0):

Static charge creates only electric Field while Current in a conductor createa both electric and Magnetic Field. As you increase the current in a conductor, associated Magnetic Field also increases. Thus increase in Current in a Conductor results in increase in associated Magnetic Field.

I don't know about your second question. However i think, since Magnetic Force depends upon charge, there increase in Current results in Increase in Magnetic Force exerted by Hirshoe magnet. I am not sire about it. Do correct me if i am wrong ..